# Is an absorbing state necessarily recurrent?

Tags: markov-chains, stochastic-calculus

> Definition:
>
> For a state i, state i is an absorbing state IFF the probability that state i returns to state i, $p_{ii}$, is 1 and $p_{ij}=0$
>
> Definition:
>
> A state i is recurrent/ persistent if the probability of state i returning to state i k-times is $p^{k}_{ii}=1$

From here, it seems that an absorbing state is a recurrent state.

Am I correct with my deduction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct: an absorbing state must be recurrent.

To be precise with definitions: given a state space $X$ and a Markov chain with transition matrix $P$ defined on $X$.

A state $x \in X$ is *absorbing* if $P_{xx} = 1$; neccessarily this implies that $P_{xy} = 0, \, y \neq x$.

Given $x \in X$, the first return time is the random time at which the Markov chain first revisits $x$,
 $$\tau_x^+ = \inf\{ n \geq 1 \, \colon \, X_n = x\}.$$

A state $x \in X$ is *recurrent* if $\mathbf{P}_x[ \tau_x^+ < \infty] = 1$; that is if the Markov chain almost surely revisits $x$ having started at $x$.

Now if $x$ is an absorbing state, then we have
$$ \mathbf P_x[ X_1 = x] = p_{xx} = 1,$$
which is to say  $\mathbf P_x[ \tau_x^+ = 1] = 1$, and in particular we have $\mathbf P_x[\tau_x^+ < \infty] = 1$, which is to say $x$ is recurrent.

Comment: is there any difference between absorbing and recurrent states?

Comment: Yes; consider the Markov chain with transition matrix $$\left( \begin{array} 0 0  & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right).$$ Then both sites are recurrent (in the notation aboeve $\mathbf P_x[ \tau_x^{+} = 2] = 1$ (i.e. we almost surely return to our starting point in exactly two steps). However neither site is absorbing since $P_{xx} = 0$ for both sites $x$. The main point is: a site is absorbing if you never leave it. A site is recurrent if you always return to it.